# Как получить элементы управления, перекрываемые визуально другим элементом управления?

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Как определить, что один из элементов видимой частью перекрывает другой?

Например, если я задал у элемента отрицательное свойство *Margin*. Или задал трансформацию. Или элементы расположены на канве. Или расположены в одной ячейке *грида*.

Может быть много способов перекрыть один элемент другим. Как это можно отследить?

Кто-то может сейчас сказать, что надо грамотно располагать элементы изначально. Но я приведу пример, когда это нереально:

Например, есть у меня самодельная стрелка для схемы. И если расположить их на форме две, они должны расположиться так, чтобы одна стрелка не залазила на другую, но *ректы* самих элементов управления вполне могут перекрываться своими прозрачными частями.

Answer (score 2):

Если вопрос только про стрелки, то стрелки - это два отрезка и, достаточно вспомнить школьную геометрию и определить пересекаются ли они, чтобы понять есть ли коллизия. Вот статья вам в помощь: http://gospodaretsva.com/urok-32-peresekayutsya-li-dva-otrezka.html

Задача же непосредственного определения перекрытия контроллов, как ни крути, будет сводится к попиксельной проверке, что недопустимо замедлит работу UI.

Comment: Я знаю, как проверить отрезки на пересечение, но в моем случае это очень сложно (я бы сказал нереально). Стрелка строится по 11 точкам (состоит из 3х фрагментов прямоугольников с треугольником на одном конце). Размеры относительны, к тому же, если к геометрии добавить комбинаторику... В общем я изначально избрал неверную тактику. Придется искать иное решение (

Comment: Стрелки всегда прямые или возможны варианты (изогнутые, зигзагом и т.д.)? Если только прямые - создайте компонент вертикальную линию со стрелкой и сверстайте таким образом, чтобы растягивалась только линия посредине (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrochon/archive/2011/01/10/custom-line-caps-in-wpf.aspx). Потом просто поворачивайте этот компонент на нужный угол и масштабируйте до нужной длины. Зная длину отрезка (ActualHeight) и угол наклона компонента можно, используя школьную геометрию, легко посчитать пересечения с другими такими же.

Comment: Линии прямые. Беда в том, что результат строится динамически. Стрелки связывают дочерние элементы с родительским (дерево в виде графа). Причем дочерние элементы (вместе со своими дочерними) лежат в контейнерах с авторазмерами. То есть контейнер со стрелкой, соединяющий один элемент с родительским скорее всего будет лежать поверх другого контейнера со стрелкой. Вот пример того, что я хочу получить. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/image_6E693012.png

Comment: Я решал такую задачу неоднократно. Думаю смогу вам помочь. Ответьте на вопрос: Используется ли граф вне визуального построения (для дальнейших вычислений) или же существует только тогда, когда отображается?

Comment: Существует только тогда, когда отображается. Хотя я мог и не правильно понять ваш вопрос. Думаю, надо переместиться в чат

Comment: Разумеется, создавайте чатрум.